# Ruby: What's an elegant way to pick a random line from a text file?

Tags: ruby, file, io

I've seen some really beautiful examples of Ruby and I'm trying to shift my thinking to be able to produce them instead of just admire them. Here's the best I could come up with for picking a random line out of a file:

```
def pick_random_line
  random_line = nil
  File.open("data.txt") do |file|
    file_lines = file.readlines()
    random_line = file_lines[Random.rand(0...file_lines.size())]
  end 

  random_line                                                                                                                                                               
end
```

I feel like it's gotta be possible to do this in a shorter, more elegant way without storing the entire file's contents in memory. Is there?

Comment: Is this more of a "how do I do this _in Ruby_" question, or more of a "how do I do this _in less than O(N) space_" question?  If the latter, investigate [reservoir sampling](http://gregable.com/2007/10/reservoir-sampling.html).

Comment: my trivial implementation would be to seek to a random position in the file and then seek forwards to a newline

Comment: @SamSaffron That won't give you a uniformly random line unless all the lines are exactly the same length.

Comment: @Zack true, though to get absolute uniformity you would have to sample all line lengths, to get reasonable uniformity you would need to sample a pile of lines randomly ... really depends on if this is a "real" problem or a "toy" problem

Comment: @Zack, that's a fascinating link. I'm interested in the latter expressed in the former, with syntax as clean as possible.

Comment: Good link, @Zack.  My answer amounts to reservoir sampling with a reservoir of 1.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do it without storing anything except the most recently-read line and the current candidate for the returned random line.

```
def pick_random_line
  chosen_line = nil
  File.foreach("data.txt").each_with_index do |line, number|
    chosen_line = line if rand < 1.0/(number+1)
  end
  return chosen_line
end
```

So the first line is chosen with probability 1/1 = 1; the second line is chosen with probability 1/2, so half the time it keeps the first one and half the time it switches to the second.

Then the third line is chosen with probability 1/3 - so 1/3 of the time it picks it, and the other 2/3 of the time it keeps whichever one of the first two it picked.  Since each of them had a 50% chance of being chosen as of line 2, they each wind up with a 1/3 chance of being chosen as of line 3.

And so on.  At line N, every line from 1-N has an even 1/N chance of being chosen, and that holds all the way through the file (as long as the file isn't so huge that 1/(number of lines in file) is less than epsilon :)). And you only make one pass through the file and never store more than two lines at once.

**EDIT** You're not going to get a real concise solution with this algorithm, but you can turn it into a one-liner if you want to:

```
def pick_random_line
  File.foreach("data.txt").each_with_index.reduce(nil) { |picked,pair| 
    rand < 1.0/(1+pair[1]) ? pair[0] : picked }
end
```

Comment: Tough choice, but yours was the only answer that addressed the memory part of the question. I wonder if there's a way to reduce the verbosity of this in a similar way to Dave's answer. Thanks!

Comment: (The `.to_f` is superfluous). Wouldn't this return nil sometimes?

Comment: @steenslag: true, given the `1.0`, the `.to_f` could be dispensed with.  But no, it won't ever return nil, because `rand` is always less than 1, so it always at least picks the first line.

Comment: I like this answer better than mine. Sure, my answer is a one-liner, but this approach doesn't have any file size limitations.

Comment: @tres - see edit for a one-liner version. But I don't think it actually reduces verbosity, and it does impede clarity IMO.

Comment: Although this is shorter, and undeniably elegant, I have voted it down because it is also "too clever". By that I mean it's difficult to understand and maintain, i.e. if I want to modify or extend it I cannot do it quickly and easily.

Comment: That is of course your prerogative, @WillSheppard, but the OP specifically asked for both "elegant" and "shorter". While the second version in my post is too short in my opinion, I think the first one is pretty clear. It's also not super-obscure, since the algorithm has been around since at least the 1999 Perl Cookbook, and is part of a well-understood class called [Reservoir sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling).

Answer (score 39):

There is already a random entry selector built into the Ruby Array class: sample().

```
def pick_random_line
  File.readlines("data.txt").sample
end
```

Comment: Wonderful, reduced the method to one line! (Should have known about `sample` myself though)

Comment: Caveat: You'd suffer if the file was big.

Comment: Note that for those holdouts still using Ruby 1.8, `sample` was called `choice` then.

Comment: Can lazy enumeration fix this?

Answer (score 4):

This function does exactly what you need.

It's not a one-liner. But it works with textfiles of **any** size (except zero size, maybe :).

```
def random_line(filename)
  blocksize, line = 1024, ""
  File.open(filename) do |file|
    initial_position = rand(File.size(filename)-1)+1 # random pointer position. Not a line number!
    pos = Array.new(2).fill( initial_position ) # array [prev_position, current_position]
    # Find beginning of current line
    begin
      pos.push([pos[1]-blocksize, 0].max).shift # calc new position
      file.pos = pos[1] # move pointer backward within file
      offset = (n = file.read(pos[0] - pos[1]).rindex(/\n/) ) ? n+1 : nil
    end until pos[1] == 0 || offset
    file.pos = pos[1] + offset.to_i
    # Collect line text till the end
    begin
      data = file.read(blocksize)
      line.concat((p = data.index(/\n/)) ? data[0,p.to_i] : data)
    end until file.eof? or p
  end
  line
end
```

Try it:

```
filename = "huge_text_file.txt"
100.times { puts random_line(filename).force_encoding("UTF-8") }
```

Negligible (imho) drawbacks:

1. the longer the line, the higher the chance it'll be picked.
2. doesn't take into account the "\r" line separator ( windows-specific ). Use files with Unix-style line endings!

Comment: By far the best option for large files, otherwise the read time will vary drastically.

Answer (score 2):

This is not much better than what you came up with, but at least it's shorter:

```
def pick_random_line
  lines = File.readlines("data.txt")
  lines[rand(lines.length)]
end
```

One thing you can do to make your code more *Rubyish* is omitting braces. Use `readlines` and `size` instead of `readlines()` and `size()`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yeah, I was wondering about that when I wrote my answer. I am trying to find out if there's a way to keep the concise syntax, while closing the file properly.

Comment: You found it, it looks like ;-)

Answer (score 1):

A one liner:

```
def pick_random_line(file)
  `head -$((${RANDOM} % `wc -l < #{file}` + 1)) #{file} | tail -1`
end
```

If you protest that it's not Ruby, go find a talk in this year's Euruko titled *Ruby is unlike a Banana*.

PS: Ignore SO's incorrect syntax highlighting.

Comment: True. Which I presume was Martí's point that it's unnatural to use Ruby outside of Unix.

Comment: I hope it's not too unnatural, if it is then I would hope that since Windows is on the [Ruby supported platform list](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby-trunk/wiki/SupportedPlatforms) we would work as a community to fix it. But that isn't an issue for stackoverflow, so I will leave it at that.

Comment: The correct command is `head -$((${RANDOM} % \`wc -l < #{file}\` + 1)) #{file} | tail -1` with escaped back ticks. Stack Overflow won't let me edit it because it's less than 6 characters.

Comment: As long as it gets the job done, in a right, elegant and efficient way

Answer (score 0):

Here a shorter version of Mark's exellent answer, not as short as Dave's though

```
def pick_random_line number=1, chosen_line=""
  File.foreach("data.txt") {|line| chosen_line = line if rand < 1.0/number+=1}
  chosen_line 
end
```

Comment: This shows shorter is not always better. Changing local variables to arguments just to save lines???

Answer (score -1):

Stat the file, pick a random number between zero and the size of the file, seek to that byte in the file. Scan until the next newline, then read and return the next line (assuming you're not at the end of the file).

Comment: This is a bad idea because the first line will *never* be picked and lines after a long line have a greater chance to be picked, so it's not random.

Comment: Good point. I guess you could just seek scan backwards and then forwards to read the line on the spot where you hit. Unless the file is huge though or performance requirements are silly; its not worth the effort.